# How can I solve this matrix ODE using python?

Tags: python, math, scipy, numerical-methods, ode

I would like to numerically compute this ODE from time 0 -> T :
[ODE equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdl55.png) where all of the sub-matrix are numerically given in a paper. Here are all of the variables :

```
import numpy as np

T = 1
eta = np.diag([2e-7, 2e-7])

R = [[0.33, 3.95],
     [-2.52, 10.23]]
R = np.array(R)
gamma = 2e-5
GAMMA = 100
S_bar = [54.23, 27.45]
cov = [[0.47, 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.14]]
cov = np.array(cov)
shape = cov.shape

Q = 0.5*np.block([[gamma*cov, R],
                  [np.transpose(R), np.zeros(shape)]])

Y = np.block([[np.zeros(shape), np.zeros(shape)],
              [gamma*cov, R]])

U = np.block([[-linalg.inv(eta), np.zeros(shape)],
              [np.zeros(shape), 2*gamma*cov]])

P_T = np.block([[-GAMMA*np.ones(shape), np.zeros(shape)],
                [np.zeros(shape), np.zeros(shape)]])
```

Now I define de function f so that P' = f(t, P) :

```
n = len(P_T)
def f(t, X):
    X = X.reshape([n, n])
    return (Q + np.transpose(Y)@X + X@Y + X@U@X).reshape(-1)
```

Now my goal is to numerically solve this ODE, im trying to figure out the right function solve so that if I integrate the ODE from T to 0, then using the final value I get, I integrate back from 0 to T, the two matrices I get are actually (nearly) the same. Here is my solve function :

```
from scipy import integrate
def solve(interval, initial_value):
    return integrate.solve_ivp(f, interval, initial_value, method="LSODA", max_step=1e-4)
```

Now I can test wether the computation is right :

```
solv = solve([T, 0], P_T.reshape(-1))
y = np.array(solv.y)

solv2 = solve([0, T], y[:, -1])
y2 = np.array(solv2.y)
# print(solv.status)
# print(solv2.status)


# this lines shows the diffenrence between the initial matrix at T and the final matrix computed at T
# the smallest is the value, the better is the computation
print(sum(sum(abs((P_T - y2[:, -1].reshape([n, n]))))))
```

**My issue is** : No matter what "solve" function im using (using different methods, different step sizes, testing all the parameters...) I always get either errors or a very bad convergence (the difference between the two matrices is too high).

Knowing that according to the paper where this ODE comes from ( (23) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.13773v4.pdf) there exists a solution, how can I numerically compute it?

Comment: Try several variations of `atol` and `rtol`. The error should scale with them. The quadratic term can make the integration very error sensitive in at least one direction.

Comment: Sorry I didnt precise that I used the smallest values possible for 'atol' and 'rtol' (around 2e-14) and the convergence is still bad.

Comment: I even used a block matrix of scale factors for `atol`, without much success. The most immediate problem can be seen in the function value of `f` at the final point. Practically this gives an almost instantaneous jump to zero starting from `T` backwards. This is very unstable in the forwards integration, so almost impossible to correctly undo. On the other hand, I did not see much difference (exception eta) from the data in the paper for the french banks. Such a rapid jump should not be part of a continuous model, it should be handled separately. But then it would not be the original model ...

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot for your feedback. What would you suggest me to do in order to numerically implement this paper properly?